# MyPHP webcall using 2 different values seperated by the & sign

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, get

I am in need of some help, please? I can successfully do a MySQL query using:

IP_Address/fund_list.php?Id_Number=555666

With this below:

```
$ID = $_GET['Id_Number'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fund_list WHERE Number = ".$ID;
```

---

Now I want to use 2 different things in my web call. Like:

IP_Address/fund_list.php?Id_Number=555666&Name=Billy

But I don't know how to write the 'get' line below.

```
$ID = $_GET['Id_Number'] & $Name = $_GET['Name'];   <-- Does not work
```

I would think the SQL select statement would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fund_list WHERE TheNumber = .$ID AND TheName = .$Name";
```

All the things I look up online, the syntax is overly confusing, I can't dissect it and make something work. Thank you.

Comment: You should really be preparing your statements, passing data directly from a query string into a SQL query is really dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you should really be preparing your statements, passing data directly from a query string into a SQL query is really dangerous.  You should also avoid using * in your SELECTs if you insist on not preparing them.

Your issue in this case is you need '' around TheName =

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fund_list WHERE TheNumber = {$ID} AND TheName = '{$Name}'";
```

Regardless, what you should be doing is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Param1, Param2 FROM fund_list WHERE TheNumber = ? AND TheName = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $ID, $Name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($param1, $param2);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
  //Your code
}
```

That code prevents SQL injection attacks, and a number of other potential issues you can create not using PDO or mysqli prepared statements.

Edit per request:

```
$ID = $_GET['Id_Number']; 
$Name = $_GET['Name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fund_list WHERE TheNumber = {$ID} AND TheName = '{$Name}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  //your code
}
```

You need '' when comparing string parameters in SQL.

Comment: I forgot to mention the most important thing, this is in my lab setup and does not and never will touch the internet or any other user but me. I am building an IVR that in itself concatenates and builds web-calls and my intense focus is on the IVR itself. I want to (if I can) keep it super simple as security is of no concern. I need to fetch everything with the SELECT * because the IVR stores all the info and acts on it. Can you perhaps just give a 2 line working example?

Comment: I tried what you said around .$NAME but nothing,   $ID = $_GET['ID_Number'] & $NAME = $_GET['Name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fund_list WHERE TheNumber = .$ID AND TheName = '.$NAME'";,

Comment: Your concatenation syntax is wrong.  Use my -exact- code example.  You can't use . to concatenate inside of a string.  It works in your initial example because you've closed the string.

Comment: Mason, thank you so, so much for helping me. I never set out to be a MyPHP/SQL code writer, as the IVR is my thing, so I just needed a query to work so I can program my IVR to act upon all that is returned. I was thinking my problem was in the $_GET line but it was in the actual SELECT line.

Comment: Happy to help!   Would you mind marking it answered?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried doing this? This always works to me
$ID = $_GET['Id_Number'];
$Name = $_GET['Name'];

Comment: That's not really an explanation of what went wrong.

Comment: I did try this, as that's exactly what I thought would work,it seems simple enough, but it doesn't work.